# 32bit or 64bit PHP on 64bit capable processor/64-bit Windows Server 2008/IIS7

Tags: php, iis, installation, 32bit-64bit, windows

I plan to install PHP on a system running on AMD Opteron/Windows Server 2008/IIS7. According to the device manager the OS is a *64-bit Operating System*. So which flavor of PHP should I install on it. If 64-bit PHP 5.3.x then will there be any gotchas? Or should I expect 32-bit PHP to run smoothly without any (performance) problems?

PS: in case you're wondering -- WPI sucked and did not work at all. It tried to download 32-bit/NTS version of PHP for Windows and failed repeatedly.

Comment: Odd that WPI failed so hard for you. I've found that the easiest method to install PHP on Server 2008, but my three have been R2. If I were in your position, I might try to figure out why WPI is bombing out.

Comment: @James: it is Windows Server 2008 R2. I am going for manual install as suggested on forums.iis.net; only question remains is whether to go for the x86 or x64 version of PHP.

Comment: To go x64 you need to make sure that all extensions you are going to use are also available for you (unless you can compile them yourself). The already compiled builds from windows.php.net as well as one offered by WPI are x32 only.

Comment: @Lazy: that's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 64bit PHP for significant performance improvement, though you can try the 32bit too !